# Creating a dummy type

Tags: c#, powershell, types

Apologies if I've framed the question incorrectly but I'm not sure where it fits in exactly.

I am executing a powershell script from C# which returns a collection of type `PSObject`. The data I want is contained in the field BaseObject and when debugging it tells me its type is `(PowerShellInside.NetCmdlets.Commands.MessageInfoObject)` and I can see all the information there. So my question is assuming that a 3rd party vendor assembly is not available to be referenced, what is the correct approach to retrieving data from this object say

```
(PowerShellInside.NetCmdlets.Commands.MessageInfoObject).Subject
```

Do you create your own version of this class omitting what you dont need or is there some neat dynamic typing that can be done.

Comment: dynamic was the correct approach, many thanks for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a POSH developer so I'll take this from the C# angle.

I'll assume `PSObject` is the equivalent of `System.Object` and `MessageInfoObject` is the type returned from the script... I'd say using something like the following should work:

```
dynamic msgInfo = ExecutePOSHScript(...);
```